# Code/script based video editing software?

Tags: video-editing, programming

I've been editing video with ffmpeg for a while and wondering if there's a more visual alternative or wrapper.

Generally speaking I'm looking for a programming orientated or script-based video production tool.

A good metaphor to this would be the programming language and software called [OpenSCAD](http://www.openscad.org/) which allows you to generate 3D models from code, I am interested in the same thing but for video production.